# Is there any specific data block can I use to retrieve the generated values from local_file resource in terraform cloud

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, terraform-cloud

This is my first question here.

```
resource "local_file" "values" {
  content  = data.template_file.values.rendered
  filename = "values-${var.environment}.yaml"
}

data "template_file" "values" {
  template = file("${path.module}/values-template.yaml")
vars {
  key1 = var.value1
  key2 = var.value2
}
```

I have used the above snippet to create a file "values-${var.environment}.yaml". we are using terraform cloud as a backend remote. what data block do I use to retrieve the "values-${var.environment}.yaml" into my local machine or to use them in below resource block.

```
resource "helm_release" "prism" {
  depends_on = [ data.local_file.prism ]
  name       = "prism"
  repository = "xxxx"
  chart      = "prism"

  values = []
}
```

which provider block should I use to deploy the helm releases in kubernetes?

```
provider "helm" {
  alias = "eks-prism-app-prod-apse2"
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.prism.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.prism.certificate_authority.0.data)
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.prism.token
    load_config_file       = false
  }
}
```

I tried with the above block, but i was blocked with **"Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable"**

I did manually import the values by saving it to local machine using **terraform state show module.manifests.data.local_file.prism > values.yaml**. Then I deployed manually from local machine using kubeconfig and exporting aws keys.

I want to automate these with out manual intervention.

Help will be appreciated and Thanks in advance.